# How to divide counts on a single table?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

This is Postgres 8.x, specifically Redshift

I have a table that I'm querying to return a single value, which is the result of a simple division operation. Table's grain looks along the likes of `user_id | campaign_title`.

Division operation is like the count of rows where campaign_name is `ilike %completed%` divided by count of distinct user_ids.

So I have the numerator and denominator queries all written out, but I'm honestly confused how to combine them.

Numerator:

```
select count(*) as num_completed
from public.reward
where campaign_title ilike '%completion%'
;
```

Denominator:

```
select count(distinct(user_id))
from public.reward
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward solution, just divide one by the other:

```
select (select count(*) as num_completed
        from public.reward 
        where campaign_title ilike '%completion%') 
        / 
       (select count(distinct user_id) from public.reward);
```

The slightly more complicated but faster solution:

```
select count(case when campaign_title ilike '%completion%' then 1 end) 
       /
       count(distinct user_id)
from public.reward;
```

The expression `count(case when campaign_title ilike '%completion%' then 1 end)` will only count rows that meet the condition specified in the `when` clause.

---

Unrelated but:

`distinct` is ***not*** a function. Writing `distinct(user_id)` is useless. And - in the case of Postgres - it can actually get you into trouble if you keep thinking of `distinct` as a function, because the expression `(column_one, column_2)` is something different in Postgres than the list of columns: `column_one, column_2`

Comment: Thanks about the `distinct` tidbit. I figured out how to do it and it actually looks similar to your second suggestion.